# How to keep information about the user in the background? [Android]

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android application that uses an activity with 3 tabs (fragments) as a main activity. The application stores all the information that it uses on firebase and for this reason every time the user signs in, he downloads the data from firebase. Here comes my problem. I have a fragment that displays the information about the current user and another fragment that shows notes the user stores on firebase. Since the information is stored on firebase and I don't want to download it on every fragment refresh I would like to store what I've downloaded and keep that information "in the background". I tried to create a class Session that keeps all the notes and the information about the user but after the refreshing/finishing of some activities and fragments the information that I stored in my Session class gets lost.

My question is:
Is there any way to keep the information about the current session in the background (something like an activity without a screen. I believe those are called services) and of course what are some best practices to do so? Here is my Session class:

```
public class Session {

    private static HashMap<String,Note> allNotes = new HashMap<String, Note>();
    private static User currUser;


    public Session(User user){
        this.currUser = user;
    }


    public static HashMap<String, Note> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }

    public void setAllNotes(HashMap<String, Note> allNotes) {
        this.allNotes = allNotes;
    }

    public static User getCurrUser() {
        return currUser;
    }

    public void setCurrUser(User currUser) {
        this.currUser = currUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look here may it helped http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is use `shared preferences` Shared Preferences allows activities and applications to keep preferences, in the form of key-value pairs similar to a Map that will persist even when the user closes the application. 
As the name suggests, the primary purpose is to store user-specified configuration details, such as user specific settings, keeping the user logged into the application.
If you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save, you should use the SharedPreferences.

Here is great link to get [started.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Also consider using parceble to send data. When we want to pass objects between two components in Android, these objects have to implements Android Parcelable interface.Parcelable Android is a serialization and deserialization mechanism as we are used in Java.

You can use realm to store data temporaily especially if the information set is big.Realm is a mobile database that runs directly inside phones, tablets or wearables. [Here.](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/)